# Template displays foreign key instead of CharField for disabled field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using Django 1.97 and have the following models:

```
class Symbol(models.Model):

    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    # more fields

class Position(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)
    # more fields

    def get_user_positions_qs(self, user):
        positions = Position.objects.all().select_related('symbol').filter(user=user).order_by('symbol')
        return positions
```

I need to display a modelform in a template for the logged in user's positions, but the `symbol` field needs to be disabled. So far I have the following in my view:

```
position = Position()
form_class = PortfolioForm
PositionModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Position, fields=('symbol', 'various_other_fields'), form=form_class)

def get(self, request):
    positions = self.position.get_user_positions_qs(user=request.user)
    position_formset = self.PositionModelFormSet(queryset=positions)
    return render(request,
                  'template.html',
                  {'position_formset': position_formset})
```

And the form:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['symbol'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': True})

    class Meta:

        model = Position
        fields = ['symbol', 'various other fields']
```

The problem is that when displaying the form, the `symbol` field only contains the foreign key id instead of the actual `symbol CharField` from the `symbol model`. If I change the form so that the `symbol` field is not disabled, then the `symbol` field in the template displays the correct value, however it then has a dropdown allowing the user to change the symbol which is not allowed.

So my question is, how do I disable the `symbol` field in the template while  continuing to display the `symbol` value found in the `CharField` from the `symbol model` (ie: not just the foreign key id pointing to that record). It appears that if you have a form that includes a field from another model, then trying to make that field disabled results in the field only displaying a foreign key instead of the actual value from the other table.

Comment: Do you actually need the field to be shown to the user at all?

Comment: Yes, the user needs to be able to see all of the fields for each position they have but they will only able to edit some of them

Comment: Problems is that you are using a Textinput widget for a FKey field, which is treated as a lookup field by default. Why not just have it be a disabled dropdown field?

Comment: @domino, could you give an example how to do that? Is there a disabled dropdown widget to use in the form that still shows the current value for that record? The user needs to be able to see what the current value is,...they just mustn't be able to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a Textinput widget for a FKey field, which is treated as a lookup field by default. Why not just have it be a disabled dropdown field?

```
self.fields['symbol'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

**Edit: Alternative solution**

Based on your comment, here's another solution that *I think* should work:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol_text = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('symbol', 'other fields')
        model = Position

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['symbol_text'].widget.attrs['value'] = self.instance.symbol
        self.fields['symbol_text'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. That does indeed work, the only problem is that this causes the loading of all available symbols for the dropdown even though it is disabled. The list of available symbols is huge (several thousand). When selecting symbols in other parts of the site, I use ajax so that I don't send several thousand symbols into the dropdown. However here with this example, im not sure how I would disable the field, show the current value, while also not loading thousands of symbol options that are not needed. Any ideas?

Comment: You could potentially limit the queryset using the fields queryset attribute. Something like `self.fields['symbol'].queryset = Symbol.objects.filter(...)`